# How to compare value of custom field with the Rules module?

Tags: 8, entities, rules

I'm using the *Entity has field* condition for the *After saving new content* event, to make sure the rule only fires when the newly created nodes contain the field, which is part of a custom content type.

I want to use the *Data comparison* condition, but the field doesn't show up in the data selector.

How can I compare the field with a value?

Comment: I'd guess it's the same as Drupal 7: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/170224/how-to-get-field-values-in-rules-condition-from-fetched-entity. Worth a look at least

Comment: Sorry to disagree with the prior comment from @Clive (it's not the same) ... My guess is that you'll now better understand why the most recent D8 release of Rules has an "alfa" qualifier. [read more ...](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/community-promotion-ads-2017/3616#3616) ... It would help however to clarify your question if you'd include the rule you have so far in your actual question

Comment: The code for it has been in the 8.x codebase for 3 years so probably worth trying @J.Dough https://www.drupal.org/node/2281107